# Right-align a flex item without an extra wrapper

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a layout where most of my items align to the left of the viewport, but one item needs to align to the right.

I would rather not use `float: right;` in this instance and would prefer to make use of `justify-content: flex-end;`

I have made a codepen which visually shows the correct layout, but it has an extra div (I've titled it `.remove-this-div`) that I'd rather not have there, as I want to keep my mark-up as clean as possible and avoid wrapper divs where they are not required

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/franhaselden/pen/mPoxBJ)

The mark-up I'm after whilst still getting the button to align `right` is like this:

```
<section>
  <div>I sit to the left</div>
  <div>I sit to the left</div>
  <div>I sit to the left</div>
  <div>I sit to the left</div>
  <button>I sit to the right</button>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 500px;
}

button { 
  align-self: flex-end;   /* `margin-left: auto` would also work */
} 

section > * {
  outline: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>I sit to the left</div>
  <div>I sit to the left</div>
  <div>I sit to the left</div>
  <div>I sit to the left</div>
  <button>I sit to the right</button>
</section>
```

[Revised Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/reRdZq)

More about flex alignment and `auto` margins here: [Methods for Aligning Flex Items](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276)

Answer (score 0):

The property you're looking for here is [`align-self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-self):

```css
section{
    display:flex;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content:flex-start;
}
button{
    align-self:flex-end;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div>I sit to the left</div>
    <div>I sit to the left</div>
    <div>I sit to the left</div>
    <div>I sit to the left</div>
    <button>I sit to the right</button>
</section>
```